# What kind of entities i should create in doctrine for this db structure

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, entities

I have two tables in DB (topic, topic_content):

[image: db structure]

what kind of entities i should create for symfony2? 
I think, i should have something like this in my symfony structure (Entities/Topic.php, Entities/Topic_content.php) help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would create Topic and Topic Content. And likely also a User Entity (because  user_id looks like a foreign key).

However, the idea in Symfony2 is to approach the application from the Model site instead of the database site. Quoting https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started-database.html:

> Development Workflows
>
> When you **Code First**, you start with developing Objects and then map them onto your database. When you **Model First**, you are modelling your application using tools (for example UML) and generate database schema and PHP code from this model. When you have a **Database First**, you already have a database schema and generate the corresponding PHP code from it.

For database first, there is a generator that will derive objects based on your schema:

- https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineCodeGenerator

The recommended approach though is to have Doctrine generate the db schema from your Entities.

Quoting [Getting Started - Generating the DB Schema](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#generating-the-database-schema)

> Doctrine has a Command-Line Interface that allows you to access the SchemaTool, a component that generates the required tables to work with the metadata.

It requires some setup, which is explained in the guide. Once you have that, you simply tell Doctrine to generate or update your schema, whenever your object structure changes.